# for loop launching more than one puppeteer instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to loop through an array of items in Node.JS and launch a puppeteer browser with the data from the array in mind.

Doing so I have run into the issue that any for-loop I try consistently does not wait for the code to finish before launching another browser, therefore launching 30+ instances of chrome at once killing my computer.

I am for looping pupeteer, launch per each array item, and only want one browser at a time and allowing the code to run and finish before opening another browser under the next array item.

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    await launchPup(tochange[i]).then(() => {}); // this runs puppeteer.launch

async function launchPup(data) {
    puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: [ '' ]}).then(async browser => {
        
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Questions about code must show the relevant portions of your code.  We can't guess what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please show your code.  You would probably have an answer already if you include your code.

Comment: fixed it and added the code

Answer (score -1):

From the code you show so far, you need for `launchPup()` to be connected to the promise that `puppeteer.launch()` returns.  You can do that by just adding `return` so you are returning the `puppeteer.launch()` promise.

```
function launchPup(data) {
    return puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: [ '' ]}).then(async browser => {
        ....
    });
}
```

Or, you can do it like this with `await`:

```
async function launchPup(data) {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: [ '' ]});
    // code that uses browser here
}
```

Then, your `for` loop with `await launchPup(tochange[i])` will be able to actually wait for that operation to finish before advancing the `for` loop.  Remember, when you `await` something, it needs to be a promise that is connected to the asynchronous operation you're trying to wait for.  You were awaiting the promise from the `async` `launchPup()` function, but that promise had no connection at all to the `puppeteer.launch()` activity.

---

Also, as you show the code here, `launchPup()` does not need to be `async` as it doesn't use `await` and you don't use any of the other features of an `async` function (auto-catching of synchronous exceptions).

And, you will generally find it cleaner to code if you don't mix `await` and `.then()`.  If you're using `await`, then actually use it instead of `.then()`.  Here's how you'd remove the `launchPup().then()` and just use the `await` you already have:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let result = await launchPup(tochange[i]);
    // do something with result here
}
```